# Kendo UI - Grid binding and n-tier applications

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd like to make use of the Kendo UI Grid component (sorting, filtering, pagination) but my application has a N-tier architecture (data access layer, business layer, and web project) so I can't provide a DbSet to the server binding.

For now, I'm binding the Grid with all entities in my database so the Grid can work with those data. But I'd like to know of a way to avoid to do "get all" requests...

Is there anyway to use it with such an architecture ?

Comment: Do I need to understand that you don't want to implement a RESTful API?

Comment: I just don't want to give direct access to the DbContext in the web project.

Comment: I thought you were using Kendo UI with JS only, but I understand you're using ASP.NET MVC bindings..

Comment: Yes that's right, I'm using ASP.NET MVC bindings.

Comment: @bod I can't help then, because I've worked with Kendo UI's grid but directly using JS

Answer (score 0):

OK I found [a thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-performance-while-doing-the-read-request-(filtering-sorting-grouping)) where the guy had the same "problem" as me (n-tier application).

Apparently the only solution is to implement a custom server binding ([see the doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding)).

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea to use a `ViewModel` in order to prevent direct access to the `Entity Class` from `View`. Here is an example for using `KendoGrid` in `ASP.NET MVC` n-tier application:

**Controller:**

```
private EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext();

public ActionResult Index_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var dataContext = db.YourEntity;
    var result = dataContext.Select(m => new
    YourViewModel
      {
          ID = m.ID,
          Name= m.Name
          //code omitted for brevity
      }
    ).ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourViewModel>()
    .Name("YourGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.ID).Title("Id");
        columns.Bound(m => m.Name).Title("Contact Person"); 
    })
    .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
    .Pageablee()
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Index_Read", "YourController"))
            .ServerOperation(false) 
            .PageSize(12)
        )
)
```

Hope this helps...